# Do I need a Korean transit visa to go through Seoul on my way to Jeju?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens, jeju

I am a Filipino planning to go to Jeju for a 4-day trip. My flight will go from Manila to Incheon then change airport to Gimpo then to Jeju vice versa.

Answer (score 7):

You will not be allowed to take this trip without a visa. Although Filipino citizens (and most other nationalities) are allowed to visit Jeju without a visa, the [rules for this program](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=1010201) say that

> You must use a direct international flight or ship to Jeju Island

There is a special program allowing groups of Chinese tourists to transit at other airports on their way to Jeju, but non-Chinese citizens are not eligible for it, nor are individual Chinese tourists not part of a recognized group.

So, you should apply for a visa to South Korea, or change your flight to arrive directly at Jeju without this transfer in Seoul.